# Is there a way to map keycloak roles to jwt claims?

Tags: helidon

I’m interested in configuring rbac using Keycloak, but unfortunately unlike IDCS, Keycloak doesn’t have a role mapper already created, so that it maps the role type grants. Does anyone has any examples/resources which might help in this case, in order to map the roles from keycloak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely covered in the Security section of the Helidon training course: [Developing Microservices using Helidon for the Enterprise and the Cloud](https://mylearn.oracle.com/ou/course/developing-microservices-using-helidon-for-the-enterprise-and-the-cloud/114850). Looks like the key is to add `microprofile-jwt` in your client.